# Event that is triggered before calling database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

Is it possible to create an event(and a listener) that will be triggered after a query is generated, but before database is called?
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events
Looks like existing lifecycle events is not what I need.

Why I need this:
We have a Symfony application that gets news from API. Sometimes it makes dozens of requests to collect certain data, which takes much time, and we want to store data in the database.
My idea is to add an intermediate service that checks whether required data is already stored in the database, and if nothing found, call the API and persist or update the data there. Thus, on controller's side the data will always be taken from database.

Comment: no, you don't need listeners. I don't see where is the problem of checking first in your database (doctrine) then if not found you set it on the API. Supposing you are using a service for your API requesting, you can call your service in your controller after the doctrine check..

Comment: @hoover_D, I thought that there might be some 'best-practices' approach for my case, because adding the same condition in each controller doesn't look flexible. 
Thank you for the answer. I will try this solution.

Comment: that's why you can create a service  and call it everytime you need

Comment: You can create a service to manage data from your API. This service will make the checking and persisting action like described. The call this service in your controller before getting data from database.